# Tapable.plugin is deprecated Nuxt JS / Vuetify

Tags: webpack, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I'm not sure whether this is a problem related to Nuxt JS, or Vuetify. Recently after setting up a new Nuxt JS project with Vuetify I have been getting an error relating to `tapable.plugin`.

This error shows when running any of the `npm run` commands *(e.g: `npm run dev`)*

Here's the error:

```
 ERROR  (node:4688) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
```

I'm not sure how to fix this error and haven't had any luck yet, I've tried various of versions.

My `package.json` file contains the following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@grpc/grpc-js": "0.3.5",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.3.6",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^2.6.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "firebase": "5.8.2",
    "firebase-auth": "0.1.2",
    "nuxt": "2.4.3",
    "vue-moment": "^4.0.0",
    "vue-resource": "^1.5.1",
    "vuetify": "1.4.4",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.0.8",
    "vuexfire": "2.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.12.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2"
  }
```

Any suggestions would help on how to fix this error, the project appears to still function correctly, but it's nasty seeing this in my terminal window and for other developers, thanks

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49942558/deprecationwarning-tapable-plugin-is-deprecated-use-new-api-on-hooks-instea
It's not a problem. It's a warning.

Comment: I installed the package listed in that answer, I still get the warning unfortunately.

Comment: @RyanHolton same with me.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an actual issue, it's a deprecation warning. It means it works, but will not with future version of that specified plugin. This plugin is a dependency of nuxtjs/pwa and has already been updated, so this will be fixed in future releases. Assuming you'll regularly update or maintain your app, the dependencies will update with it (via `npm upgrade` or `yarn upgrade` or even `yarn upgrade nuxt`)

For reference: https://github.com/nuxt-community/pwa-module/issues/120

Comment: Mine says `ERROR  (node:2531) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on .hooks instead`, and when I browse to the local server at http://localhost:3000/, it's a Chrome error page: "This page isn’t working localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" So it seems more serious than mere deprecation.